# Cordova barcodescanner plugin (windowphone 10) throw error

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm working with Cordova barcodescanner plugin. When I press a button to open the scanner, it works. But When I click the button to close, it guives me an error and crashes the app. On android that button don't appear and if I press back button, it returns to app. But on windowsphone, if I click back button or the button that appear, it crash the app, instead of return.... Here is more info:

Visual Studio breaks on: throw error;

Console output:

Error in Success callbackId: BarcodeScanner1115739946 : TypeError: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference

SCRIPT5007: Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library code at line 314, column 13 in ms-appx-web://io.cordova.myapp6d8fa2/www/cordova.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post some related codes?

Comment: Hi I solved the problem using other method. Thanks Anyway :D